# Dedicated SQL Pool: "Parse error at line: 4, column: 5: Incorrect syntax near 'OPENROWSET' "

Tags: t-sql, azure-synapse

I am using Azure Synapse. I have created a dedicated SQL Pool. I am trying to use the below T-SQL script to query data from my Azure Gen 2 account:

```
SELECT
    TOP 100 *, result.filename()
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://bidi65.dfs.core.windows.net/taxi/raw/trip_data_green_parquet/year=*/month=*/*.parquet',
        FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
    )  
    WITH (
        VendorID INT, 
        lpep_pickup_datetime datetime2(7)
        )   AS [result]
```

I get the following error:

> Parse error at line: 4, column: 5: Incorrect syntax near 'OPENROWSET'.

When I used the same script to query data from my Serverless SQL Pool it worked.

Comment: The OPENROWSET function is not supported in dedicated SQL pool.

Comment: Can we query data from an azure data lake via dedicated sql pools or is this also not supported?.

Comment: You can use or create external table based on parquet file and the query the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-openrowset)

> **The OPENROWSET function is not supported in dedicated SQL pool.**

To access external files, you need to build an external data source, external file format, and external table on the dedicated SQL Pool.

**Sample Code:**

```sql
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.external_file_formats WHERE name = 'SynapseParquetFormat') 
    CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT [SynapseParquetFormat] 
    WITH ( FORMAT_TYPE = PARQUET)
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.external_data_sources WHERE name = 'fsnp2_dlsgp2_dfs_core_windows_net') 
    CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [fsnp2_dlsgp2_dfs_core_windows_net] 
    WITH (
        LOCATION = 'abfss://<container_name>@<storageaccount_name>.dfs.core.windows.net' 
    )
GO

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[sample] (
    [Col1] int,
    [Col2] nvarchar(4000),
    [Col3] nvarchar(4000),
    .......
    [ColN] nvarchar(4000)
    )
    WITH (
    LOCATION = 'parquetefilename.parquet',
    DATA_SOURCE = [fsnp2_dlsgp2_dfs_core_windows_net],
    FILE_FORMAT = [SynapseParquetFormat]
    )
GO


SELECT TOP 100 * FROM [dbo].[sample]
GO
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Please correct me if I'm wrong. I've understood your code to do the following:

1. CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT: Tells it what type of file to expect.
2. CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE: Tells it where the file is
3. CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE: Creates a view like table which will allow us to query the data

Comment: yes, it works in that order only.